# What do the coloured dots in firephp output mean?

Tags: php, debugging, firephp

I've seen green, orange, & grey dots, and they don't seem to correspond to variable types… any ideas?

I didn't find any mention of them in the FAQ, etc: http://www.firephp.org/Wiki/Reference/FAQ

[image: the beginning of firephp output with dots shown at left]

Comment: Obviously those dots are the visibility indicators, as stated in the change log. I suggest to check if the visibility (public, private, protected) of your vars is corresponding to the dot colors.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! got any more info? (I couldn't find this in the changelog).. Post an answer?

Comment: I have updated the FAQs: http://www.firephp.org/Wiki/Reference/FAQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As replied in the comments: This looks like the visiblity Indicator to me, mentioned in the [changelog](http://www.firephp.org/Wiki/Development/Release02).

Comment: Ah! tx, missed that.. that led me to the description:
  
_"FirePHP will now log and display non-static private and protected object members. If they are declared static they can be logged with PHP 5.3. The variable viewer will indicate the visibility with a little icon. Red is private, orange is protected and green is public. Grey means undeclared (you have assigned a value but not declared the variable in the class) and the square means it is static."_

http://www.christophdorn.com/Blog/2008/10/22/firephp-02-released/